# Using CSS animations to bump up div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I have a table of div's that I am trying to animate. I want to create an effect where a new div comes in an "bumps up" the previous div's. Here is a fiddle with the three messages. Right now, you can see that Message i3 is overlaying Message 2. Instead, I want Messages 1 and 2 to bump up. What's the easiest way to do this? I am going to be bumping up Message 3 and adding a Message 4 eventually, and 5, and 6, etc.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3fcbfbuu/

HTML:

```
<div class="prewrapper">       
<div class="sentmessage ">
    <div class="messagetext ">
        <div id="conversation1" >Message 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sentmessage ">
    <div class="messagetext ">
        <div id="conversation5" >Message 2</div>
    </div>
</div>      
</div>
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper_l">
    <div id="part3" class="sentmessage">
        <div class="messagetext ">
            <div id="conversation2" >Message 3</div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
setTimeout(
    function(){

$("#wrapper_l").animate({bottom:  '0%'},{duration: 500});


        }   ,1000)
```

CSS:

```
.fullconversation {
height:32%;
width: 100%;
display: block;
position: relative;
}

.prewrapper{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
}

.wrapper {
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
bottom: -200%;
}

.messagetext{
display: inline-block;
}

.prewrapper{
width: 100%;
}

.sentmessage{
border-top-width: 2px;
border-top-style:solid;
border-top-color: #e3e3e4;
width:100%;
height:100%;
display: block;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Thank you for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using absolute positions for the wrapper, it's best to put them in a normal flow, and use CSS3 translate to animate the newly added message.

```js
setTimeout(

  function() {

    $("#wrapper_l").addClass("in");

  }, 1000)
```

```css
.fullconversation {
  height: 32%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.global-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.prewrapper {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
}
.wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 200px);
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  position: absolute;
}
.wrapper.in {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0);
  position: relative;
}
.messagetext {
  display: inline-block;
}
.prewrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
.sentmessage {
  border-top-width: 2px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: #e3e3e4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="global-wrap">
  <div class="prewrapper">
    <div class="sentmessage ">
      <div class="messagetext ">
        <div id="conversation1">Message 1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sentmessage ">
      <div class="messagetext ">
        <div id="conversation5">Message 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper_l">
    <div id="part3" class="sentmessage">
      <div class="messagetext ">
        <div id="conversation2">Message 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! I have edited the jsfiddle here, slowed down a little (http://jsfiddle.net/3fcbfbuu/3/) I still have a little problem, though, because I want it to be a smooth transition. This way, the other classes "jump up" and then the other rises slowly to join them. The animation will be slow enough that you will be able to tell the difference.

Comment: I posted a separate question for that part. Thank you for helping me get going!